# Linq query with ICollection condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Please I need your help, for the past two days I have been trying to solve a Linq query...

These are my DbSet classes:

```
public class Payement
{
    [Key]
    public int ID,
    public string a,
    public string b,
    public int status_request {get;set;}

    public ICollection<beneficiaires> Beneficiaires { get; set; } = new List<beneficiaires>(); 
}
```

Beneficiaires class:

```
public class beneficiaires
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string a {get;set;}
    public string code {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public Payement Payements { get; set; } = null;
    public int ID { get; set;}
}
```

From the above classes, a payement can have many beneficiaires, what I want is to select only Payements that have a specific code from beneficiaires.

This is my query:

```
List<Payement> payments = 
    await _DbContext.Payements
                    .Include(b => b.beneficiaries.Where(c => c.code.Equals('08')))
                    .Where(p => (p.status_request == 1))
                    .Take(5)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

But this query is taking all payements with the `status_request = 1`, but I want only payements with `status = 1` for beneficiaires with code 08.

Can someone help me please?

Regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The where condition must be

`.Where(p => (p.status_request == 1) && p.beneficiaries.Any(c=>c.code.Equals('08')))`

The condition that you include in the `Include` function instruct EF to load only items in beneficiaries with the condition. Remove this condition from the `Include` if you want all beneficiaries for each payment.

**Where condition in Include**

This code return filtered payments, and each payment has the beneficiaries collection filled with all data:

```
List<Payement> payments = await _DbContext.Payements
  .Include(b => b.beneficiaries) // don't add condition here
  .Where(p => 
      p.status_request == 1 &&    
      p.beneficiaries.Any(c=>c.code.Equals('08'))
  .Take(5).ToListAsync();
```

This code return the same filtered payments, but for each of them only beneficiaries with code equal to 08 are loaded:

```
List<Payement> payments = await _DbContext.Payements
  .Include(b => b.beneficiaries.Where(c=>c.code.Equals('08'))
  .Where(p => 
      p.status_request == 1 &&    
      p.beneficiaries.Any(c=>c.code.Equals('08'))
  .Take(5).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Hello @Roberto Ferraris, thanks so much i appreciate let me update will back to you

Comment: Hello @Roberto Ferraris thanks its fine, have a nice day